# freemaker Template(FTL) + sending Email + Java1.6

Tags: java, freemarker

I Have created FTL template for sending email from my application.
I want to add company logo in signature part. I have following template in and am giving the logo.png from the same folder even it will not display logo in email.

```
<html>
<body>

Hi ${to},

<p style='color:green;'>${body}</p>

 Regards,<br/> 
${from}.<br/> 
<img width="50" height="50" src='logo.png' alt="img"></img>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any other way to do it ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't magically send the image along with the email. You need to either encode and send the image ([read about MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME)) or put the image on a server and give an absolute URL as the `src`.

Comment: If I want to send it from any desktop tool then I need to encode right? or is it only possible to send it via web Apps?
sry for the silly question completely new to FTL.

Comment: FTL/FreeMarker doesn't deal with email-specific issues, it's just a general purpose tool for generating text. You have to combine it with JavaMail or such for that. If you already have an application that sends mails based on FTL-s, then you should check if they have added any custom FTL directives (like, `<@img ... />`) or anything to support sending images.